# Calendar, need a way to hide Sat and Sun?

Tags: javascript, html, date, calendar

I'm trying to allow my application to hide weekend days, my calendar is stored within a string then printed to innerHTML. How would I go about hiding both Saturday and Sunday.

My calendar prints like the following:

Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday

Code:

```
calendarString = '';
calendarString += '<table width="100%" height="425" data-role="table" border="1" bordercolor="#c0c0c0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">';
calendarString += '<tr>';
calendarString += '<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\" align=\"center\" valign=\"center\" width=\"40\" height=\"22\">Sun<\/td>';
calendarString += '<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\" align=\"center\" valign=\"center\" width=\"40\" height=\"22\">Mon<\/td>';
calendarString += '<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\" align=\"center\" valign=\"center\" width=\"40\" height=\"22\">Tue<\/td>';
calendarString += '<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\" align=\"center\" valign=\"center\" width=\"40\" height=\"22\">Wed<\/td>';
calendarString += '<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\" align=\"center\" valign=\"center\" width=\"40\" height=\"22\">Thu<\/td>';
calendarString += '<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\" align=\"center\" valign=\"center\" width=\"40\" height=\"22\">Fri<\/td>';
calendarString += '<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\" align=\"center\" valign=\"center\" width=\"40\" height=\"22\">Sat<\/td>';
calendarString += '<\/tr>';
thisDate == 1;

for(var i = 1; i <= 6; i++){
    calendarString += '<tr>';
    for (var x = 1; x <= 7; x++){
        daycounter = (thisDate - firstDay)+1;
        thisDate++;
        if((daycounter > numbDays) || (daycounter < 1)) {
            calendarString += '<td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#888888\" height=\"30\" width=\"40\">&nbsp;<\/td>';
        } else {
            if (checkevents(daycounter,monthNum,yearNum,i,x) || ((todaysDay == x) && (todaysDate == daycounter) && (todaysMonth == monthNum))){
                if ((todaysDay == x) && (todaysDate == daycounter) && (todaysMonth == monthNum)){
                    tempweek = i;
                    tempdayofweek = x;
                    calendarString += '<td style=\"vertical-align: top;\" bgcolor=\"#AAFFAA\" height=\"30\" width=\"40\" onClick=showevents(' + daycounter + ',' + monthNum + ',' + yearNum + ',' + i + ',' + x + ')>' + daycounter + '<\/td>';
                } else 
                    calendarString += '<td style=\"vertical-align: top;\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFC8\" height=\"30\" width=\"40\" onClick=showevents(' + daycounter + ',' + monthNum + ',' + yearNum + ',' + i + ',' + x + ')>' + daycounter + '<div id="amountevent" style="padding-left:5px;max-height:8px; height:8px; width:30px; max-width:30px;white-space: nowrap;">' + displayeventnumber(daycounter, monthNum, yearNum) + '</div><\/td>';           
            } else 
                calendarString += '<td style=\"vertical-align: top;\" bgcolor=\"#f9f9f9\" height=\"30\" width=\"40\">' + daycounter + '<\/td>';
        }
    }
    calendarString += '<\/tr>';
}
calendarString += '<\/table>';
var object=document.getElementById('calendar');
object.innerHTML= calendarString;
thisDate = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a class="weekend" attribute on the table cells for Sunday and Saturday. Then use javascript to set the CSS styling for that class to:

```
.weekend {display: none;}
```

Update:
More generally if your table looked something like:

```
<table class="calendar">
    <tr><td class="weekend">Sunday</td><td>Monday</td><td>Tuesday</td><td>Wednesday</td><td>Thursday</td><td>Friday</td><td class="weekend">Saturday</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="weekend"></td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td class="weekend">6</td></tr>
    ...
    <tr><td class="weekend">28</td><td>29</td><td>30</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td class="weekend"></td></tr>
</table>

<button type="button" onclick="hideWeekends()">Hide Weekends</button>
```

And style:

```
table.calendar {width: 100%}
```

And javascript:

```
function hideWeekends() {
    // apply display: none style to elements with classname of "weekend". I recommend using jQuery if available.
}
```

Comment: That sort of works, it hides my title of Sunday and saturday but doesnt do anything with the whole row.

Comment: What do you want it to do to the row? Or do you mean column? If you want it to hide all the Sunday and Saturday elements just be sure to add that class on those table cells as well. (e.g., when date.getDay() returns 0 or 6)

Comment: i mean to column, which would be best:
Hiding the columns or 
re-running the script, meaning i could make the table full screen (when i hide them it doesnt make the table full screen.

Comment: See my edit for a way to use the style to keep it full screen