# Don't show saturday and sunday in calender javascript

Tags: javascript, calendar

I'm making a calender in javascript but I don't want to show saturday and sunday. I have searched a lot but I didn't find any good solution for this. I would appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: What calendar? You don't give enough information

Comment: I guess you just don't show any date where `date.getDay()` returns 0 or 6. What have you tried?

Comment: Visit this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21609167/calendar-need-a-way-to-hide-sat-and-sun

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({ beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends })
```

Comment: Hi @Thamothara, please explain your code instead of just showing it.

Comment: The function takes a date as a parameter and must return an array with [0] equal to true/false indicating whether or not this date is selectable and 1 equal to a CSS class name(s) or '' for the default presentation. It is called for each day in the datepicker before is it displayed. $(".selector").datepicker({ beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends })